# Node does not detect correct arch on Raspberry Pi arm64

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian, arm64, binaries

Node does recognize the correct arch being used. This results in some trouble getting the correct binaries from some dependencies.

`uname -m` or `arch` returns `aarch64`

`node -e 'console.log(process.arch)'` returns `arm`

How can I fix this? Tried rebooting and re-installing node.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processarch "The operating system CPU architecture for which the Node.js binary was compiled." . So this is not a "detection" of the used arch. It is the detection of the "architecture for which the Node.js binary was compiled".

Comment: So any way to force node js to install as 64 bit? Every time I install node by default detects `armv7l`

Comment: Did you install the 64-bit version of Raspberry Pi OS? Your kernel being 64bit doesn't mean much.

Comment: Did a full reinstall. Seems fine now! Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by doing a full 64-bit re-install of the os.